# Beating the twins

Tags: terraria

What should I use to beat the twins? I used the true nights edge with titanium armour the first time, but after the update I'm using my hollowed armour and the same weapon, but Spazmatizm always kills me in the first minute of the battle.

With the new update, the bosses are harder. What should I do?

Comment: kill the laser one first, its super easy to avoid the flamethrower on mine tracks

Comment: I am confused by what your saying. You say that with the patch, spaz now kills you quicker. However, all patch notes I find list **nerfing** the damage these bosses do. While health pool has increased, there is no reference to their damage ability increasing, or any other indication that they have been altered, apart from a changes to their health, damage reductions, and drop changes. In fact, difficulty wise, there is no change listed since 2014..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use strong armour, bring potions, use a rangerd or magic weapon and try to avoid being hit. Always stay on the move.